# What is the equivalent polar equation of $x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

It's a question in the textbook that I have and I am having a hard time understanding it. How am I supposed to get the polar equation with this format?

Comment: Multiply out the binomial-square and use the substitutions $ \ x^2 + y^2 \ = \ r^2 \ $ and $ \ y = r \sin \theta \ . $

Answer (score 2):

Converting to polar, you have $x = r \cos(\theta)$ and $y = r \sin(\theta)$. So make these substitutions and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Just substitute: $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$:

\begin{align*}
r^2\cos^2(\theta) + (r\sin(\theta) - 1)^2 =& r^2\cos^2(\theta) + r^2\sin^2(\theta) - 2r\sin(\theta) + 1 = 1 \\
r^2 - 2r\sin(\theta) + 1 =& 1 \\
r^2 - 2r\sin(\theta) = 0 \\
r(r - 2\sin(\theta)) = 0 \\
r = 0, r = 2\sin(\theta)
\end{align*}

Well, clearly, $r = 0$ is not correct (it's only mathematically correct because of the equations), so this leaves: $r = 2\sin(\theta)$

Comment: I think you forgot about the $r^2$.

Comment: You are right...I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

I would expand 
$(y-1)^2\to y^2-2y+1$
, making the equation 
$x^2+y^2-2y+1=1$
, which simplifies to 
$x^2+y^2=2y$
. 
$x^2+y^2$
 can be replaced by 
$r^2$
, and 
$y$
 can be replaced by 
$r\sin\theta$
, so 
$r^2=2r\sin\theta$
.